# Scilab GUI as a mini project

Tags: scilab

What are some good mini projects in Scilab involving GUI and plotting ? If possible please share the code for one such product.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look on this [Slideshow from openeering](http://www.openeering.com/sites/default/files/LHY_Tutorial_Gui.pdf). It explains how to create a GUI in Scilab. Also the [Scilab Ninja](http://scilab.ninja/scilab-recipe-4-gui-basics/) gives a GUI tutorial.